Handcraft and Craftman
I need to know what is the difference between handcraft and craftman? I want to use the noun that describes old fashioned jobs that used to do fringes in clothes and so on.

Welcome! Have you looked up 'craftman' in a dictionary? Even if the word you have in mind is 'craftsman' that is the person doing the work, not the work itself.

Fringe making is a handicraft. Handcrafted or handmade fringes are sold on Etsy by crafters or skilled artisans (but rarely by craftsmen and never "craftman"). Jesus was a master craftsman, maker of custom parts and such, they say, more so than a regular carpenter.

@HippoSawrUs: crafters is incredibly rare compared to craftsmen. So rare that this chart says Ngrams not found: made by crafters

I couldn't fine a term specific to fringe and ribbon and hemming work, probably because it was such an integral part of making anything out of woven fabrics. I'd be tempted use needlecraft as general term that includes the adornment of garments.

Welcome ! I think your question should read as follows : "I need to know what the difference between handcraft and craftsman is.

@FumbleFingers - crafters is a very common word in context; see craft shows or sites.

@HippoSawrUs: Do we speak the same language? Did you even consider the implications of my NGram chart? I even checked Google Books for needlework / clothing / shirts / beer / cheese / jewelry / made by crafters, and didn't find a single instance of any of them. I finally found one instance of furniture made by crafters, but "common" it ain't.

@FumbleFingers - made by crafters is like sh*t by poopers; that's probably it. I consider Ngrams witchcraft in October; maybe next month.

Oh, FumbleFingers, literally. I get it now; I'm slow, my bad.

I notice you yourself silently switched from handcraft to handicraft for the noun, in your first comment. I just charted handcrafts,craftmen,handicrafts,craftsmen. The first 2 practically flatlined, and it's not even that those are "old-fashioned" terms - they never had much currency.

handcraft is a verb - but it's very rarely used as a verb anyway. We normally only use the Past Participle adjectivally...

He makes and sells handcrafted pottery

...where the "active" verb in He handcrafts pottery is an unlikely utterance.

craftman is a noun. But note that it's a very uncommon version of craftsman (my Firefox spellchecker underlines the former in red! :) ...

...where both terms mean exactly the same - A person (esp. a man) who is skilled at a particular craft; a worker in a skilled trade; an artisan.

Note that the OP shouldn't be looking for a "noun that describes old fashioned jobs" anyway - you need an adjective for that. And in that exact context, it's probably best to refer to hand-sewn or hand-stitched clothing...

